# How to load JSON/API data using https.request and Node.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to load weather data. I have front end code that was doing this perfectly but I need to move this to back end. I moved a library of my functions over to Node.JS. I was using $.getJSON but was told I should use https.request for the new version. Here's my code:

```
getTextWeatherUsingStationUsingRequest: function(theStation){

    const http = require("http");
    const https = require("https");

    thePath = 'stations/' + theStation + '/observations/current';
    // theURL = 'https://api.weather.gov/stations/' + theStation + '/observations/current';


    function requestTheData(){

        var options = {
          protocol: "https:",
          hostname: "https://api.weather.gov/",
          path: thePath,
          port: 80,
          method: "GET"
        };
        var instaRequest = https.request(options);

         instaRequest.on("response", function(res){
            console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
            console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);

            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
            });

          console.log("response");
          console.log(res.statusCode);
          console.log(res.statusMessage);
        });

        instaRequest.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
        });

        instaRequest.end();

    }

    requestTheData();
```

I'm getting this error and can't figure out what's going on:

```
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://api.weather.gov/stations/ https://api.weather.gov/stations/:80
```

Comment: Remove https from host in the options. `hostname: "api.weather.gov/",`. You might need to remove trailing slash as well.

Comment: Try remove protocol from the options.

Comment: Before even seeing any answers I got it working by:               protocol: "https:",
              hostname: "api.weather.gov",        but now I'm getting a STATUS: 403  Forbidden   You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;api&#46;weather&#46;gov&#47;" on this server.<P>

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS generally uses port 443, so lets change that. Also, the API shows the hostname should be the raw URL and the path should be the remainder of the route (with a leading slash) similar to this:

```
    thePath = '/stations/' + theStation + '/observations/current';

    ...

    var options = {
      hostname: "api.weather.gov",
      path: thePath,
      port: 443,
      method: "GET"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Before even seeing any answers I got it working by: 
protocol: "https:", 
hostname: "api.weather.gov",

but then I was getting a STATUS: 
     403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access 
     "http://api.weather.gov/" on this server.

I seemed to remember that you are required to pass something in through headers so I added this under "method: "GET","

```
          method: "GET",

          headers: {
            'Accept'       : 'application/json',  
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent'   : 'MY-UA-STRING'
          }
```

And, voila, now I'm getting JSON weather data. It didn't work until I added the 'User-Agent'. Do you guys know what this needs to be (and/or point me to a place that describes this)?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.